# Jenkins integration with Checkmarx

Tags: jenkins, checkmarx

I have an issue when integration `Jenkins` with `Checkmarx`.

Checkmarx version: 8.90.4

Jenkins version: 2.176.3

Have provided checkmarx URL and credentials in Configure system, but when try to connect using test connection it throws me error:

> Failed to parse json response: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)):
>   expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false'
>   or 'null') at [Source: (String)"

Checkmarx URL is reachable from my local browser.

Need to get success during test connection.
Please provide a solution

Comment: if you google the exact error message you'll see some links to github repos telling that that the response that the Jenkins server receives from the Checkmarx server is in a different format from what it expects (JSON/XML Serialization/Deserialization. Most likely a proxy or firewall between these 2 servers might have modified the response during a test connection. Do you think any of these are true @Bhuvanesh Kumar?

Comment: I have done Google search on this error.. But none helped out.. These both servers sits in same network.. I don't think firewall blocking issues.. If the response was in different format then how can we convert to JSON/XML to make jenikns readable. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

The Checkmarx URL should be https://{FQDN}

Notice: Normally you access the Checkmarx portal from browser by using this URL, https://{FQDN}/CxWebClient